# ruby on rails - difference between using JUST 'belongs_to' versus using BOTH 'has_many' and 'belongs_to'?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

What is the difference between using just `belongs_to` on one model versus having `has_many` on one and `belongs_to` on another?

As an example:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

versus

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is no difference. The association only matters from the perspective of the loaded model. If you have `class Book belongs_to :author`, you'd be able to call `@book.author`; whilst you would *not* be able to call `@author.books`.

Comment: You should look into how [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)'s work (of which `ActiveRecord` is very much one). When you declare an "association" in your models, that's just giving `ActiveRecord` a reference to follow. It does nothing for the base level SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guessing each of the methods would facilitate adding a different set of additional methods to the associated class

for ex, if had to guess, with `belongs_to`, you would, in part, get ability to call association on an instance of `Book`:

```
@book.author
```

with `has_many`, if I had to guess, you would, in part, be able to call association on instance of `Author`:

```
@author.books
```

also, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

and

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

in case those may be of interest